# How to open a file that the user gives in output screen using c++

Tags: c++, file

I want the user to give the file name in output screen,for the file to be opened while running the program .More specifically, if the user gives a file name in output screen, my program should open that file for him. How can i code this using files in c++? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: You do know about the [C++ input/output library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)?

Comment: Output screen? Do you mean console? Open file and do something with it?

Comment: @zch yes, i want the user to give the name of the file which he wants to open in the console o/p screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string filename, line;
    std::cout << "Input file name: ";
    std::cin >> filename;

    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    if(!infile)
        std::cerr << "No such file!" << std::endl;
    else {
        std::cout << "File contents: " << std::endl;
        while(infile >> line)
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

contents of `test.txt`:

```
hello
world
how
are
you
```

program output (on console):

```
Input file name: test.txt
File contents: 
hello
world
how
are
you
```

the way this works is, you declare two strings - one that will be the `filename` and the other that will be serve as a temporary buffer for each `line` in file.
when the user inputs a file name, depending on whether the file exists or not, the program will either output an error, or declare and initialize a file stream `infile` (this basically opens a stream to your file and allows you to extract [or input] data from the desired file).

once that is done, the program will read the file line by line `while(infile >> line)` and output the contents of each file to console.

Comment: Thanks @stellarossa, I have one more doubt. If the file is in someother location, how can i open that file? I tried getting the path of the file from the user, but i couldn't store the path as a string. Can u help me pls...

Comment: @JefreeSujit what do you mean, why wouldn't you be able to store the file path in a string?

Comment: i use linux, so my directory starts with /home/.../file.txt so while getting the above path from user, i get segmentation fault because the path starts with '/'.

Comment: @JefreeSujit i too am on linux and tried the above piece of code by entering `/home/stellarossa/Desktop/test.txt` and it worked.